# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row error

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

Im currently reffering a ecommerce lesson using laravel 8.when creating categories for the products im keep getting this error message while migrating.

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `products`)**

This is my `create_products_table`

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('price');
            
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

and here is `create_category_product_table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoryProductTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');


             $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
             $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('category_product');
    }
}
```

Much appreciate if someone can teach me to solve this. Thank You!

Comment: If you want to drop products then you have to drop all the tables which have an FK to it first or set foreign keys off (which is probably not a good idea)

Comment: @P.Salmon Why not simply drop FKs? Why the whole tables?

Comment: @Akina Very true..Waiter more coffee

Comment: Check the sequence of your migrations and seeders - ensure parent before child. `products` and `categories` should be before `category_product`.